# Integrating ng-bootstrap in to ASP.NET Core JavaScript Services (Angular) project

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, ng-bootstrap, asp.net-core-2.0, asp-net-core-spa-services

I'm using [ASP.NET Core 2.0's JavaScript Services](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/) with [Angular](https://angular.io/) and trying to integrate [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home).

I installed `ng-bootstrap`:

> `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

I added it to `webpack.config.vendor.js`:

```
...
const treeShakableModules = [
    '@angular/animations',
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/forms',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap',  // <-- down here
    'zone.js',
];
...
```

I added `NgbModule` to the imports of my `app.module.shared.ts`:

```
...
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
...
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        NgbModule.forRoot(),  // <-- this guy
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            ...
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppModuleShared {
}
```

I clean the solution and run:

> `c:\...>webpack && webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js`

Everything builds fine.

Running:

> `c:\...>dotnet run`

Attempting to load the page results in the following error:

> NodeInvocationException: Prerendering timed out after 30000ms because the boot function in 'ClientApp/dist/main-server' returned a promise that did not resolve or reject.

This is quite obviously related to prerendering.  So I am currently attempting to create a mockup of `ng-bootstrap` using only the components I want to use, which will not invoke any promises (or will use dummy promises that resolve immediately), and does not invoke the DOM.  This will be imported in `app.module.server.ts`...

```
import { NgbModule } from './components/ng-bootstrap-mockup/ng-bootstrap'
```

...and *the standard*...

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'
```

...will be used in `app.module.browser.ts`, **instead of using *the standard* in `app.module.shared.ts`**.

These will of course both be imported in their respective `app` modules...

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        ...
    ]
})
...
```

So my question is, am I missing something?  Is there a better way to deal with this other than to create a mockup like the one I described above?

Comment: my guess is that since you haven't used any of the ng-bootstrap elements the treeshaking is dropping it and your server side rendering fails. Try to add something and see if the error will change

Comment: @Yaser I am using the carousel.  NgbModule shows up in `ClientApp/dist/vendor.js`.

Comment: I think if you going to use it for share the functionality you don't have to use it with `NgbModule.forRoot()`, just `NgbModule` and then in every app you are going to add it like this: `NgbModule.forRoot()`

Comment: have you tried putting in [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA] under schemas list for app.module.server.ts and just NgbModule is good under imports don't have to use forRoot() i guess..... that solved the issue for us

Answer (score 1):

**You Can Add Bootstrap 4 to Angular project**

> Install bootstrap Alpha release using NPM:

```
npm install --save bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6
//We chose a specific version to ensure future releases doesn’t break the sample. Optionally, run the following command to install the latest pre-release package.

npm install –save bootstrap@next
//Once the package is downloaded, add Bootstrap references in .angular-cli.json.

//Modify styles configuration to add Bootstrap CSS

styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
],

//Modify scripts configuration to add jQuery, Bootstrap and Tether JS files.

"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js",        
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
],
```